# jQuery UI Draggable function is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I've included the jquery library, afterward the jQuery UI library, and it still doesn't work. I am Using Google Chrome browser.

code Follows:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="type/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( ".drag" ).draggable();
    });
</script>

<div id="aboutBox" class="boxLook boxBg drag"></div>
```

I can't find any solutions anywhere. The debugger says that the method draggable doesn't exist. But I've added jQuery AND jQuery UI, and the paths are correct! it just doesn't work.

Comment: The jquery ui js file you are using, does it include the draggable module? Try recreating your jquery ui file from their website and make sure draggable is included.

Comment: i opened the jquery ui JS file and searched for draggable and it existed, i also added ui-draggable to the about box. Still Nothing

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have one of these problems:

1. Your jQuery or jQuery UI Javascript path files are wrong
2. Your jQuery UI does not include draggable
3. Your jQuery or jQuery UI Javascript files are corrupted
4. Your div is unstyled and empty, therefore there is nothing to drag
5. Something is colliding with your jQuery or jQuery UI so it doesn't work

Your code is correct, and it should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/u7zWA/

Comment: Okay, Strangly i got it to work. Rather than adding the scripts through my project a fetched the code from "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" And it works! Yaay! But Now i Have Another Problem, I can Drag The Div. But When i release the div, it returns to its original Position :s

Comment: `draggable({ revert: false })`, if my answer helped you please upvote and accept :)

Comment: 6. You are loading you ui script before jquery

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work for me. Using latest Edge.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="type/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="type/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( ".drag" ).draggable();
    });
</script>

<div id="aboutBox" class="boxLook boxBg drag"></div>
```

You have to implements the draggable component to your project, and include it ! http://jqueryui.com/download

Comment: It's probably included in `js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js`. "custom" is the suffix used to denote custom builds of the jQuery UI library.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using an older version of jQuery UI. I replaced the old reference with the following and everything started working as intended.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I had another event bound to mousemove that contained a  `e.stopPropagation();` which prevented the `.draggable()` mouse code from working.

```
$(document).on('mousemove', '*', function (e) { MyFunction(e); });

function MyFunction (sender, e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    ...
}
```

The solution was to remove the `e.stopPropagation();` and re-evaluate its implementation.

Comment: console output: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined". Could you please point a reason?

Comment: check you are passing `e` through the function tree

Comment: Thanks bro. I spent a good 6 hours trying to figure out what was wrong. Turns out there was a discrepancy between two .js files I had loading in the same view.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by setting the dialog's position as fixed. It worked like a magic, after hours of stress:

```
.ui-dialog {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your draggable object is already loaded in the viewport. If it is not, it won't work properly.

My advice is to add this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">             
$(function() {                         
    $( ".drag" ).draggable({ helper:'clone' });
});
 </script>
```

JUST AFTER the draggable object to be absolutely sure that everything is loaded at the correct time.

When you'll be sure everything is ok, then you'll be able to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential reason is that you've turned all drag events off somewhere else in your code, using something like this:

```
window.ondragstart = function () { return false; };
```

This will stop the jQuery UI drag event from firing.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and i have solve my issue with **update the Jquery UI** file.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had another file in the codebase using `draggable` and then I just wanted to reuse the class name.

**This fixed it for me:** I renamed the CSS class to be different from the previous one.

---

**Previous Implementation:**

```
  $(".old_css_class_name").unbind("droppable");
    $(".old_css_class_name").draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move",
        connectToSortable: ".css_name_to_sortable_implementation" //optional
    });
```

**New Implementation:**

```
$(".new_css_class_name").unbind("droppable");
    $(".new_css_class_name").draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move",
        connectToSortable: ".new_name_to_sortable_implementation" //optional
    });
```

---

**Optional:** You might want to add this line of code before implementing draggable

```
$(".the_new_css_class_name").unbind("droppable");
```