# jQuery UI Draggable: Not working properly but copied?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I wish to get a grasp on jQuery and jQuery UI. This stuff is cool and I may see its potential though I'm no king in javascript, far from it!

I have written this piece of code in an HTML file written by hand for pedagogical purpose.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>01 - jQuery UI Draggable Basic Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
        .dragarea {
                height: 500px;
                width: 500px;
                background: grey;
        }

        #draggable {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                padding: 20px;
                background: #ccc;
                cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { $( "#draggable" ).draggable(); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dragarea">
        <div id="draggable">Drag me</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Yet, it's working properly when copied from this [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) website.

I have also read this tutorial on [How to create a simple drag and drop with jQuery](http://www.ericbieller.com/2010/06/24/how-to-create-a-simple-drag-and-drop-with-jquery/), plus plenty of other StackOverflow's Q/A's:

1. [jQuery UI Draggable Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159118/jquery-ui-draggable-not-working)
2. [Can't get JQuery Draggable plugin to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144188/cant-get-jquery-draggable-plugin-to-work?rq=1)

Just to name a few.

When I say it doesn't work properly, I mean that I can see my two DIV sections on the screen with the correct styles, and I cannot drag the drag-able rectangle, it just selects the text and the page just like I was trying to copy the text. Here's the result on screen.

[image: On-screen result of my code above]

What's wrong with my code? Might someone please tell me?

Thanks for your support! =)

Comment: Edited the code to close the `script` tags properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Script tags are not self closing.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js" />
```

***[FIDDLE: BROKEN](http://jsfiddle.net/UnqLe/)***

Should be

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

***[FIDDLE: FIXED](http://jsfiddle.net/YxBP9/)***

Comment: +1 for pointing me out an error. I changed the code as suggested and it still does not drag.

Comment: Are you sure?  I made 2 fiddles and the one with the fixed script tag works fine.  Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: I hand-type the code in Notepad++, then save the file into an HTML, then I double-click on it to open it in Chrome. It doesn't work on my side. =( I shall do fiddles too, I guess. Might you include the fiddle link in your answer?

Comment: They are in there.  It's called `BROKEN` AND `FIXED`

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't pay attention to the links. I just did copy my code into the HTML section of Fiddle and it works. I don't get why it doesn't on my side...

Comment: one thing to be careful of when copying and pasting from jsfiddle is it sometimes adds an illegal char to the end of the code.  Always copy and paste to notepad++ first to make sure.. then paste it into your code.

Comment: Your last comment's suggestion made it work. I have taken the hand-written code from Notepad++, tested it in Fiddle, then copied it back to Notepad++ and it does work now. My sincerest thanks! =)